# Why does Rsync fail with a "File Exists (17)" error when syncing to an EncFS partition?

Tags: synchronization, rsync

This command successfully synchronizes all files in `src` with the `dest` folder on Windows' `C:` drive.

```
$ rsync -av /cygdrive/c/src /cygdrive/c/dest
```

However, if the dest folder is located in an EncFS partition, say `X:`, I get an error.

```
"/cygdrive/x/dest/.a.txt.G5csoY" -> "src/a.txt": File exists (17)
```

In the end, file `a.txt` is removed from the `dest` folder by rsync. So running `rsync` again with the same parameters successfully copies the file.

How can I sync these two directories by running rsync just once?

Comment: May be dest dir is symlink under a sshfs-mountpoint? Use a real dir name.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use something like `--temp-dir="/cygdrive/C/"` , where `C:\` is location for temp files. I found reasons to do so in this mailing list post, ["rsync fails if it cannot stat destination file"](http://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2006-May/015641.html).

Comment: That post seems to indicate the opposite of what you're suggesting... "This is caused by the use of a temp-dir on a different filesystem than
the destination file.". That advice suggests you should do `--temp-dir=/cygdrive/X/tmp`. But, the rsync man page says , "The default behavior is to create the temporary files in the receiving directory."